# Gravity Forms use comparison operators (greater than, less than) in field filters

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using the GFAPI::get_entries() function. One of the fields is a date field.

I would like to get those entries, whose date is bigger than a certain date. A bit like the `compare` parameter in WP_Meta_Query.

How can I accomplish this?

Current code:

```
$search_criteria = array(
    'status'        => 'active',
    'field_filters' => array(
        'mode' => 'all',
        array(
            'key'   => '4',
            'value' => $current_user->ID
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => '1',
            'value' => $listing->get_id()
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. Comparison operators work also for date types. This was my solution. It receives a date range (previously parsed) and uses it to search entries with a greater value.

```
// Parsing the input date received via $_POST
$date_fin_parsed = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $_POST['date_fin']);
$date_fin_parsed = $date_fin_parsed->format( 'Y-m-d' );

$search_criteria = array(
           'status'        => 'active',
           'field_filters' => array(
               array(
                   'key'   => 146, // Date field ID
                   'operator' => '>', // Later dates
                   'value' => $date_inicio_parsed,
               )
           ),
);
```